# What is the phase of a gauge coupling?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory

We typically take gauge couplings to be real and positive. Why do we impose these two conditions? I assume this is a requirement because gauge theories without positive couplings are unphysical or is the phase not observable to begin with. But I'm not sure why either of these would be the case.

Answer (score 4):

A negative coupling leads to a Hamiltonian that is unbounded from below, and hence unphysical, since there is no lowest-lying energy state.

Similarily, a phase would mean the Hamiltonian is not self-adjoint, and time evolution would not be unitary.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it trivial that the Hamiltonian is unbounded, it's not clear to me when it's an interaction between more then 1 field? Also regarding the phase. I agree that the interaction  would be complex, but then you could just add the hermitian conjugate like we with yukawa interactions?

Comment: @JeffDror: The Hamiltonian will be unbounded from below because you can create a particle-antiparticle state from the vacuum, but for negative couplings, opposite charges repel, so the energy of a particle-antiparticle state can be *lower* than that of the vacuum. Adding more particles lowers the energy even further, so the Hamiltonian is unbounded from below. The conjugate of the gauge coupling term $\bar\psi A \psi$ is $\bar\psi A \psi$, if I'm not mistaken, so you really gain nothing by adding the conjugate expression.

Comment: I think I'll try to add a more formal argument why the Hamiltonian becomes unbounded, but it might take a while.

Comment: Good point about the effect of adding a complex conjugate. That makes sense. I'm now suspicious about the argument that the Hamiltonian is unbounded since if the particle is oppositely charged doesn't the coupling in Abelian gauge theories flip sign?